# Почему создается объект абстрактного класса через реализацию cингелтона?

Tags: android

Есть абстрактный класс.

```
 @Database(entities = {Note.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class NotesDataBase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static NotesDataBase dataBase;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "notes2.db";
    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

    public static NotesDataBase getInstance(Context context) {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            if (dataBase == null) {
                dataBase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, NotesDataBase.class, DB_NAME).
                        allowMainThreadQueries().build();
            }
        }
        return dataBase;
    }

    public abstract NoteDao noteDao();
}
```

Как я понимаю создать экземпляр абстрактного класса невозможно.
Но следующий код его возвращает:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dataBase = NotesDataBase.getInstance(context);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if(actionBar != null){
        actionBar.hide();
    }
```

Как так? Сбит с толку.

Comment: там потому что замешано слово static

Comment: Все равно это нарушение ООП. Абстрактный метод не только не имеет реализации, но и возвращает тип определенный в интерфейсе и не имеющего реализации(NoteDao).
Ответ какой то другой.

Comment: А как вы определили, что возвращается именно он, а не что-то от него отнаследованное посредством вашей аннотации?

Answer (score 4):

Вся магия происходит на этапе кодогенерации. У вас в проекте (в папке `app/build/generated/source`) создаётся файл `ИМЯ_АБСТРАКТНОГО_КЛАССА_Impl.java`, в котором находится объявление класса, реализующего написанный вами абстрактный класс.

Экземпляр именно этого класса возвращает билдер библиотеки.